# The sed does not change all pattern in below code

Tags: sed

I am trying use sed today and I have a quick question.
Why below code does not change all 'day's?

```
echo 'day night day' | sed 's/day/night/'
```

The output is :

> night night day

But I thought it will change all of the "day"s
Please help me to understand how to do it and why it did not change that.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To make multiple replacements in a single line, you must add the `g` (global) flag:

```
$ echo 'day night day' | sed 's/day/night/g'
night night night
```

You can also use *number* in place of `g` to replace only the *numberth* instance:

```
$ echo 'day night day night day' | sed 's/day/night/2'
day night night night day
```

As noted in [the GNU sed documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command):

> Note: the POSIX standard does not specify what should happen when you
>   mix the g and number modifiers, and currently there is no widely
>   agreed upon meaning across sed implementations. For GNU sed, the
>   interaction is defined to be: ignore matches before the numberth, and
>   then match and replace all matches from the numberth on.

Since Ubuntu uses GNU sed, that is indeed how it behaves:

```
$ echo 'day night day night day' | sed 's/day/night/2g'
day night night night night
```

Comment: Thank you. I think it did not change because sed is line oriented.

Comment: @ChristianoMoshar You are right on that one.  The `g` will do them all, but if you wanted to change only the last one it would be `echo 'day night day' | sed 's/day$/night/'`  where the `$` after the word means apply to last match.  If you wanted to only do the first match, leave it the way it is as that is the default.

Answer (score 0):

By default, sed is not "greedy".  If your regular expression is 's/day/night/g' then your output will be "night night night", which I think you want.

Comment: Greediness is really a property of repetition operators IMHO - in that sense (which is the usual one, I think), `sed` most certainly **is** greedy by default - for example `echo 'day night day' | sed 's/.*day/night/'` will replace everything up to and including the *last* instance of `day`. Perl (which is also greedy by default) provides a non-greedy modifier e.g. `perl -pe 's/.*?day/night/'` will only replace the first `day`

Comment: Fair point about my careless use of "greedy".  Anyway, the point is that the regex only matched once; you need to tell it if you want to match more than once.